# Changing domain name from localhost to custom in meteor.js

Tags: meteor, localhost

I tried to change domain name of my project with the following command

```
$ set ROOT_URL=http://mixer.example.com:3000
$ meteor
```

And that seems to work according to output

```
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://mixer.example.com:3000
   Type Control-C twice to stop.
```

But I can't open page at this address, it still opens only on localhost. What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to run it with the domain locally...you need to change your hosts file (/etc/hosts) and add the domain and point it to localhost. In your case, it would look something like this:

127.0.0.1 mixer.example.com

Answer (score 1):

#### This worked for me without doing anything else:

```
ROOT_URL=http://mydomainname.test:3000/ meteor --port 3000 --settings settings.local.json
```

[image: meteor localhost custom domain name]